# make.copy() Google-Api-Script/JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to copy a Google slide into a Drive folder. When I run the script it looks like my two variables for destination and source are not defined. What am I missing?

```
   function makeCopy() {
    
      var name = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getName() + " Copy ";
      var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("1234567890");
    
    // gets the current Google Sheet file
      var source = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
    
    // makes copy of "file" with "name" at the "destination"
      source.makeCopy(name, destination);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SlidesApp.getActivePresentation()` returns a [Presentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation), but [`.makeCopy(name, destination)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makecopyname,-destination) is a [File](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#) method.

Instead of having `source` store the presentation, use the [presentation's ID](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation#getId()) to [get the file](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilebyidid) and store it instead.

```
function makeCopy() {
  var name = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getName() + " Copy ";
  var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("123j3GbzhSB3m8xG-MijssMkynXHxNanl");

  // gets the current Google Sheet file
  var source = DriveApp.getFileById(SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getId());

  // makes copy of "file" with "name" at the "destination"
  source.makeCopy(name, destination);
}
```